# Get GeoJSON from a database by the AJAX method for OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
 if (ol.proj.proj4 && ol.proj.proj4.register) { ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4); }
            
            var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
                $.ajax({ 
                    type: 'GET', 
                    url: 'readGeojson.php', 
                    //data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data, status) { 
                        console.log(data);
                        geojson = data
                    }
                })
            );
            
            function reverseTransform(coordinates, output, dimensions) {
                var dims = dimensions || 2;
                for (var i=0; i<coordinates.length; i+=dims) {
                  var j = coordinates[i];
                  coordinates[i] = coordinates[i+1];
                  coordinates[i+1] = j;
                }
                return coordinates;
            }
            
            features.forEach(function(feature){
                feature.setId(undefined);
                feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
            });
            
            var map = new ol.Map({
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
                    }),
                    new ol.layer.Vector({
                        source: new ol.source.Vector({
                            features: features
                        })
                    })
                ],
                target: 'map',
                controls: ol.control.defaults({
                        attributionOptions:
                            ({
                                collapsible: false
                            })
                    }).extend([
                        new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
                        new ol.control.FullScreen(),
                        new ol.control.ScaleLine()
                        
                    ]),
                    interactions: [
                        new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom(),
                        new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
                        new ol.interaction.DragPan(),
                        new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom()
                    ],
                view: new ol.View({
                    center: ol.proj.transform([698282.236, 377375.758], 'EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857'),
                    zoom: 14,
                })
            });
```

I want to get a GeoJSON from the ajax database and display co-ordinates on the automatic map of how to load the page in OpenLayers.

I tried this way:

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'readGeojson.php', 
                //data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, status) { 
                    console.log(data);
                    geojson = data
                }
            })
        );
```

And I got this error from the code:

```
Uncaught Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined
    at Af (GeoJSON.js:299)
    at e.readFeatureFromObject (GeoJSON.js:110)
    at e.readFeaturesFromObject (GeoJSON.js:146)
    at e.readFeatures (JSONFeature.js:56)
    at get_map (test1.php:3410)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test1.php:18) Af @ GeoJSON.js:299 e.readFeatureFromObject @ GeoJSON.js:110 e.readFeaturesFromObject @ GeoJSON.js:146 e.readFeatures @ JSONFeature.js:56 get_map @ test1.php:3410 onclick @ test1.php:18
```

---

This code generate GeoJSON :

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) AS geojson FROM a_final order by ST_XMin(geometry) LIMIT 10";
    // echo $sql;
    $dbcon = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres password=72342");
    
    $query = pg_query($dbcon,$sql); 
    $geojson = array(
        'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
        'features'  => array()
    ); 
    while($edge=pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {  
        $feature = array
            (
            'type' => 'Feature',
            
            'geometry' => json_decode($edge['geojson'], true),
             'crs' => array(
                'type' => 'EPSG',
                'properties' => array('code' => '31700')
            ),
            'geometry_name' => 'wkb_geometry',
            'properties' => array
            (
                'ogc_fid' => htmlspecialchars($edge['ogc_fid']),
                'area_id' => $edge['area_id'],
                'building_id' => $edge['building_id'],
                'type' => $edge['type'],
                'area' => $edge['area'],
                'owner' => $edge['owner'],
                'description' => $edge['description'],
                'administration' => $edge['administration'],
                'address' => $edge['address'],
                'property' => $edge['property'],
                'layer' => $edge['layer'],
                'extendedentity' => $edge['extendedentity'],
                'linetype' => $edge['linetype'],
                'entityhandle' => $edge['entityhandle'],
                'text' => $edge['text'],
                'wkb_geometry' => $edge['geometry']
            )
        );
        array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
    }
    
    pg_close($dbcon);
    header('Content-type: application/json',true);
    echo json_encode($geojson);
```

---

I tried to directly copy GeoJSON into the pickup variable and go so ....

GeoJSON:

```
  {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698282.236,377375.758],[698289.591,377372.136],[698183.88,377182.298],[698182.72,377197.045],[698282.236,377375.758]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"01020000000500000000FED478544F2541002731087F081741408D972E634F25418195438B70081741295C8FC28F4E254181E92631790517410AD7A3708D4E2541027B142EB405174100FED478544F2541002731087F081741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698289.591,377372.136],[698295.211,377369.369],[698184.767,377171.028],[698183.88,377182.298],[698289.591,377372.136]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"010200000005000000408D972E634F25418195438B700817411E31086C6E4F2541C022DB79650817416039B488914E25414108AC1C4C051741295C8FC28F4E254181E9263179051741408D972E634F25418195438B70081741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698307.17,377363.481],[698311.314,377361.44],[698321.211,377356.567],[698188.867,377118.9],[698185.72,377158.908],[698301.257,377366.392],[698307.17,377363.481]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"0102000000070000007F3D0A57864F25417F438BEC4D081741A09BC4A08E4F2541415C8FC2450817412131086CA24F254102A69B44320817417F6CE7BB994E25419A9999997B0417410AD7A370934E254180C0CAA11B051741FF8095837A4F2541C0726891590817417F3D0A57864F25417F438BEC4D081741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698191.282,377088.192],[698336.526,377349.026],[698348.895,377342.935],[698195.874,377068.133],[698192.739,377069.67],[698191.282,377088.192]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"010200000006000000E04D62909E4E254101A69BC40004174140DF4F0DC14F25417FBE9F1A14081741A0703DCAD94F2541BFA370BDFB071741A0ED7CBFA74E254102273188B00317413F355E7AA14E2541007B14AEB6031741E04D62909E4E254101A69BC400041741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698223.512,377072.661],[698215.605,377058.461],[698210.805,377060.814],[698218.769,377075.117],[698363.812,377335.59],[698368.608,377333.228],[698223.512,377072.661]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"01020000000700000021DD2406DF4E2541032FDDA4C2031741608FC235CF4E2541426210D889031741C1F5289CC54E25414037894193031741415EBA89D54E254100D9CE77CC031741C076BE9FF74F2541C3F5285CDE071741A0C64B370150254100D578E9D407174121DD2406DF4E2541032FDDA4C2031741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698227.007,377070.852],[698219.142,377056.727],[698215.605,377058.461],[698223.512,377072.661],[698368.608,377333.228],[698372.141,377331.489],[698227.007,377070.852]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"01020000000700000000819503E64E254141B07268BB0317416139B448D64E254141B072E882031741608FC235CF4E2541426210D88903174121DD2406DF4E2541032FDDA4C2031741A0C64B370150254100D578E9D4071741E126314808502541816ABCF4CD07174100819503E64E254141B07268BB031741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698230.934,377068.819],[698223.116,377054.779],[698219.142,377056.727],[698227.007,377070.852],[698372.141,377331.489],[698376.112,377329.534],[698230.934,377068.819]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"010200000007000000803F35DEED4E254180EFA746B3031741205A643BDE4E2541022DB21D7B0317416139B448D64E254141B072E88203174100819503E64E254141B07268BB031741E126314808502541816ABCF4CD07174161105839105025417FE5D022C6071741803F35DEED4E254180EFA746B3031741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698237.435,377065.453],[698229.695,377051.554],[698223.116,377054.779],[698230.934,377068.819],[698376.112,377329.534],[698377.635,377328.784],[698382.096,377326.587],[698382.684,377326.297],[698237.435,377065.453]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"010200000009000000DF51B8DEFA4E2541803BDFCFA50317413F0AD763EB4E2541C0C64B376E031741205A643BDE4E2541022DB21D7B031741803F35DEED4E254180EFA746B303174161105839105025417FE5D022C60717415FB81E45135025417FE5D022C307174180E926311C50254140871659BA071741803F355E1D50254182C42030B9071741DF51B8DEFA4E2541803BDFCFA5031741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698241.362,377063.42],[698233.669,377049.605],[698229.695,377051.554],[698237.435,377065.453],[698382.684,377326.297],[698386.655,377324.342],[698241.362,377063.42]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"010200000007000000601058B9024F2541027B14AE9D031741002B8756F34E2541BF1E856B660317413F0AD763EB4E2541C0C64B376E031741DF51B8DEFA4E2541803BDFCFA5031741803F355E1D50254182C42030B907174100295C4F25502541823F355EB1071741601058B9024F2541027B14AE9D031741"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698278.389,377044.249],[698271.143,377031.236],[698233.669,377049.605],[698241.362,377063.42],[698386.655,377324.342],[698424.092,377305.908],[698278.389,377044.249]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"","area_id":null,"building_id":null,"type":null,"area":null,"owner":null,"description":null,"administration":null,"address":null,"property":null,"layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":null,"entityhandle":null,"text":null,"wkb_geometry":"01020000000700000000022BC74C4F254140DBF9FE50031741C04B37493E4F254101FCA9F11C031741002B8756F34E2541BF1E856B66031741601058B9024F2541027B14AE9D03174100295C4F25502541823F355EB1071741C09F1A2F7050254180C0CAA16707174100022BC74C4F254140DBF9FE50031741"}}]}
```

My GeoJSON its this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"2","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[698282.236,377375.758],[698289.591,377372.136],[698183.88,377182.298],[698182.72,377197.045],[698282.236,377375.758]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"31700"}},"geometry_name":"wkb_geometry","properties":{"ogc_fid":"2","area_id":"2","building_id":"2","type":"test","area":"test","owner":"test","description":"test","administration":"test","address":"test","property":"test","layer":"Green Area","extendedentity":null,"linetype":"test","entityhandle":null,"text":"test","wkb_geometry":"01020000000500000000FED478544F2541002731087F081741408D972E634F25418195438B70081741295C8FC28F4E254181E92631790517410AD7A3708D4E2541027B142EB405174100FED478544F2541002731087F081741"}}]}
```

Comment: Pasting your geojson in geojson.io shows a line in north. please check the geojson and transformation.

Comment: There seems to be `EPSG:31700` projection definition missing in your code.

Comment: Yes i put the EPSG and not working....

Comment: But it's not included in the above code, just registering of proj4 module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below  is code that works. It's almost exact copy of code from question, except that `EPSG:31700` definition is added and geojson data is imported through `geojson` variable.

```
<script src="geojson.js"></script>

proj4.defs('EPSG:31700',
     '+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=28,-121,-77,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');                      
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson);

features.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.setId(undefined);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: features
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions:
                ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
        }).extend([
            new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
            new ol.control.FullScreen(),
            new ol.control.ScaleLine()

        ]),
        interactions: [
            new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
            new ol.interaction.DragPan(),
            new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom()
        ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([698282.236, 377375.758], 'EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 14,
    })
});
```

Here is the result:

[image]

EDIT1: If you want to read data with jquery ajax, where data is stored in file `data.geojson` on server, then replace line

```
var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson);
```

with

```
var features;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.geojson",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
       features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have done to do ... the problem is that I have to bring that json from the php database through ajax ... :(

Comment: Could you please make me a code on Ajax to figure out what I'm wrong with? I honestly do not understand when I take the data from the database on ajax does not go and when I put them directly into the barrier goes ......: ((

Comment: Checked for this line: var geojson = $.getJSON('json/geojson.json', function(data) { });

Comment: @CoderCoder42 See my updated answer for solution with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok, but from errors you got. I would say you have some problem with geometry returned from your PHP script. Line 110 from Openlayers GeoJSON.js
is:

```
const geometry = readGeometry(geoJSONFeature['geometry'], opt_options);
```

And next error in stack (line 146) is returning feature. Maybe because of error reading invalid geometry you got undefined feature. Try to inspect validity of returned JSON from your PHP script.

Check your code with some GeoJSON for which you are certain that it is correct. There is some problem with geometries because data uploaded to geojson.io show only one horizontal line in the north.